# Getting EOleSysError Class not registered but don't know which DLL is missing - Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Running a program on a machine that doesn't have the IDE I get this error. I understand that the problem is a missing or unregistered DLL or OCX.

Lots of postings on how to fix it, but all the answers assume that you know which DLL/OCX is missing.

Using madExcept I see that there are 76 DLL's listed as "modules".

I'm using Delphi XE for development.

Is there a way to get a list of DLL dependences for a program with the missing ones highlighted in some way.

Comment: "Class not registered" is a COM error. COM libraries are not linked statically, they are loaded dynamically by COM, so they don't show up in traditional dependant checks. I suggest you run the program on a working machine and use the IDE debugger or SysInternals Process Explorer to take note of the libraries it successfully loads, then run the program on the non-working machine and use SysInternals Process Explorer/Monitor to see what libraries it loads before the error occurs. Then compare the two lists and copy+register missing libraries until the error goes away.

Comment: Or, if you know the exact COM class name/ID that is failing (SysInternals Process Monitor can show you the name/ID that COM is looking for in the Registry), you can try researching online if that class belongs to a known library.

Comment: Try some debugging. What class is being created when the error is raised?

Comment: Doesn't madExcept call stack tells you exactly what the source of that exception?

Comment: Thanks to David Heffernan, kobik and Remy Lebeau for replying.  Apologies for the slow response - I was my granddaughter's wedding yesterday and the organisation was a higher priority for me.

Comment: Extra information:- The non-working machine is Windows XP - we use it to make sure our app runs on old gear.  However, this problem is evident on client's Windows 10 machines, I just don't have modern machine that has never had the Delphi IDE on it to use as a test rig.

Comment: I have madexcept running but that doesn't tell me which DDL/OCX?COM library it is failing on.

Comment: madExcept has this in its stack trace:-   main thread ($dd8):
005f3260 +014 apm v4.10.13.12.exe ComObj OleError  
005f326f +007 apm v4.10.13.12.exe ComObj OleCheck  
008b15a2 +056 apm v4.10.13.12.exe OleCtrls LicenseCheck  
008b16b5 +0e9 apm v4.10.13.12.exe OleCtrls OleControl.CreateInstance  
008b1031 +125 apm v4.10.13.12.exe OleCtrls TOleControl.Create

Comment: The XP machine is a problem as SystemInternals isn't downloadable for that PC.  Also the DLL's seem to get loaded in a totally different order between the XP and the W10, so comparing the successful load with  wrong un tells me nothing.

Comment: You need to go further in the stack call. which line/code is calling `TOleControl.Create`? My guess is, there is an activex control on one of your forms which is not registered in the system.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was indeed relating to a DLL.

I had thought that the difference between working and non working systems was the presence of the IDE, but instead it was the fact that Skype had been installed on some PC and not others.

The culprit (I think) was the Skype4COM.DLL.  At some stage Skype functions had been added to the app.  As we had decided to remove those functions from the app for other reasons (mainly wanting to stay independent of Skype), I removed them and the app runs OK.

Just putting that DLL onto the non-working PC did not fix the problem, but that may have been related to the old XP.

Thanks to @David Heffernan, @kobik and @Remy Lebeau for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old. But searching the internet for solution I found this thread. I just ran into the same issue. I deployed a Delphi app on a customer machine and got the same error.

The app was using `TMediaPlayer` and I found out that the target machine was a `Windows 10 N`, without Media features.

Running an elevated `PowerShell` and the [command](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/hnibuc/install_media_feature_pack_via_powershell/fxcimh2/)

```
Get-WindowsCapability -online | Where-Object -Property name -like "*media*" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

solved the issue after a Windows restart.